# How to create a ListView like this in android?

Tags: android-listview

I need your help. How to create a ListView like this ?

How to draw the line in between and put the ball in the center ?

Attached the image below .

http://s28.postimg.org/aqxxjxk1p/Memilog_listview.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view like that and then write a class which extends say `ArrayAdapter` then
you need override

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);
}
```

Comment: I need help in defining the layout (your_layout).